# Put Ticket Into "Waiting on Customer" status

Tags: jira

I have a new installation for Jira Service Tickets hosted by Atlassian.

I would like to put tickets into a status of "Waiting on Customer" but I can not figure out how to do that.

This is what I see:

[image]

I can see the category of "Waiting on Customer" on the left, so I would guess this is available to me.

I would expect to see it in my workflow but my workflow looks like this:

[image]

I read this link on Atlassian:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Service-Desk-questions/Change-status-to-Waiting-for-Customer/qaq-p/56836

That link does not apply to me because:

1. It seems to reference that I should see a "Waiting on Customer" status in my workflow.  As you can see above I do not see that.
2. It references a "Respond to Customer" button.  I do not have that.  I have a "Comment" section and when I type a comment I get a "Share with Customer" button.

Comment: @pnuts - I would be happy to adjust the workflow if that will fix the problem, but it seems to me this should be already the way it works so i would not expect to do that.  Also, I am new to JST so I would have to learn how to do that.